# How to use built-in OpenSSL function instead of a shell command in PHP?

Tags: php, openssl, websecurity

I want to use [his code](https://github.com/ralphreijs/ios_autoconfig) for creating iOS profiles for my test server. However, `generate.php` use shell commands which are blocked by default in the php.ini settings. I know I can just disable it and then after filling correct data to a variables everything works fine, but I have two concers about this:

- Can I store that page directly on a machine where the mail server resides?
- How to store/access certificates in a secure way so nobody could download my private key from the server and potentially compromise it?
- I tried to rewrite `generate.php` in order to get rid of shell commands, but I seem I've failed since I get this:

`file ./unsigned.mobileconfig not foundfile .profile/SERBA.mail.mobileconfig not foundfile .profile/SERBA.mail.mobileconfig not found`

instead of a file containing mail configuration in the [Apple Format](https://developer.apple.com/business/documentation/Configuration-Profile-Reference.pdf). What I am doing wrong here?

This is what I've done in order to create a file and sign it:

```
# Remove previously generated files
$filenames = [
    "./unsigned.mobileconfig",
    ".profile/$CONFIG_NAME",
];
#$remove1 = `rm unsigned.mobileconfig`;
#$remove2 = `rm profile/$CONFIG_NAME`;

foreach ($filenames as $filename) {
    if(file_exists($filename)) {
        unlink($filename);
    }
    else {  
        echo "file $filename not found";
    }
}

# Create the mobileconfig
$fp = fopen('unsigned.mobileconfig', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $data);
fclose($fp);


# Set header for downloading the file contents
header("Content-type: plain/text");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=". $CONFIG_NAME);

# Sign the mobileconfig, variables are defined before entering that part of the PHP file
$ifSigned = openssl_pkcs7_sign("unsigned.mobileconfig", "profile/$CONFIG_NAME", $SERVER_CRT, $SERVER_KEY, array(PKCS7_TEXT [$CA_CRT]));
#$signcmd = `openssl smime -sign -in unsigned.mobileconfig -out profile/$CONFIG_NAME -signer $SERVER_CRT -inkey $SERVER_KEY -certfile $CA_CRT -outform der -nodetach`;


# Get the file contents
$file = file_get_contents("profile/$CONFIG_NAME", true);
echo $file;

# Remove temporary files
foreach ($filenames as $filename) {
    if(file_exists($filename)) {
        unlink($filename);
    }
    else {
        echo "file $filename not found";
    }
}
#$remove1 = `rm unsigned.mobileconfig`;
#$remove2 = `rm profile/$CONFIG_NAME`;

 ?>
```

Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: Please embed all textual information (code, error messages, ...) as formatted text in your question. Off-site resources may disappear after some time leaving your question without the required details; and also such information isn't searchable on Stack Overflow.

Comment: what if they contain 100+ lines?

Comment: _what if they contain 100+ lines?_ ... then you need to reduce it to the critical code sections. Also note that some [down-vote questions](https://idownvotedbecau.se) having [too much code](https://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/) – see also [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). – A good question is focused and specific which (usually) won't require a lot of code. Questions requiring a lot of code usually ask _here's (all of) my code, I've got no idea what's wrong with it or what I should do; please help_.

Comment: I edited my question, please let me know if that looks fine.

Comment: Looks better than before – still there's a lot of information which doesn't seem that relevant for your problem. If I understood you, then your problem is that `$ifSigned = openssl_pkcs7_sign("unsigned.mobileconfig", "profile/$CONFIG_NAME", $SERVER_CRT, $SERVER_KEY, array(PKCS7_TEXT [$CA_CRT]));` cannot find the just before written (profile) files which should be signed – I'd focus on investigating that error, and on that question. (Apart from that, have you really asserted that when you edit your `php.ini` to allow shell commands and use the original php that everything works as expected?)

Comment: The original php code worked after allowing shell commands in `php.ini` without any problem, but having that allowed bugs me if it's safe to have it on the same machine where the mailserver is (as I wanted to keep mailserver certificates in one place).